# While Login from Cordova app server sends Object reference not null

Tags: angularjs, cordova, web-applications

I am sending login details from a Cordova app in the asp.net service layer. It checks for sender referrer. In our Cordova app we have `file://`. Is it good to use this as referer in the service layer?

If it's not please tell any other good way to authorise my customer app?